# Why the IBM natural language classifier is returning DecodeError. python

Tags: python, jwt, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

Why the IBM natural language classifier is returning DecodeError ?
Im try to classifier a collection, but now it returning error.
A week ago, its was runing perfect

MY CODE

```
classes_values = []
for i in range(0, len(materiasg), 10):
  classes = natural_language_classifier.classify_collection(
    classifier_id,
    [{"text":materia} for materia in materiasg[i:(i+10 if i+10 < len(materiasg ) else len(materiasg))]]).get_result()
  c = [sorted([[dicionario_classe["class_name"], dicionario_classe["confidence"]] for dicionario_classe in i["classes"]],key=lambda x: x[0]) for i in classes["collection"]]
  classes_values += c
 
classes_values = np.array(classes_values)
```

OUTPUT

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DecodeError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-80-d2b25928198b> in <module>()
      3   classes = natural_language_classifier.classify_collection(
      4     classifier_id,
----> 5     [{"text":materia} for materia in materiasg[i:(i+10 if i+10 < len(materiasg ) else len(materiasg))]]).get_result()
      6   c = [sorted([[dicionario_classe["class_name"], dicionario_classe["confidence"]] for dicionario_classe in i["classes"]],key=lambda x: x[0]) for i in classes["collection"]]
      7   classes_values += c

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jwt/api_jwt.py in decode_complete(self, jwt, key, algorithms, options, **kwargs)
     78         if options["verify_signature"] and not algorithms:
     79             raise DecodeError(
---> 80                 'It is required that you pass in a value for the "algorithms" argument when calling decode().'
     81             )
     82 

DecodeError: It is required that you pass in a value for the "algorithms" argument when calling decode().
```

Comment: its work with a curl =(

Answer (score 5):

You may be having this problem due to the newest version of PyJWT (2.0.0).
Try going back to the previous version with 'pip install PyJWT==1.7.1' and see if your project works.

Comment: THANK YOU. This worked with my IBM Watson Voice Engine based program. You are a life saver....

Comment: It worked for me as well. Total lifesaver, thank you!